# Is there an easy way to add custom bot to Teams conversation

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We want to easily add our custom bot to the conversation window when an user ping us. Currently we have to upload the zip file of the bot to the conversation every time. Ideally the bot should be found by searching in the "Add People" - just like how the real people been added. Several questions:

- I noticed that the custom bot can be published. However, we don't want it to be published publicly, it needs to be Microsoft internally. Is it possible?
- If the bot got published, can we add the bot to a conversation just by searching in the "Add People" box? If not, is there anyway to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to publish the bot for your organisation only, you can publish it in your tenants app catalog. You need to be a global admin or have the teams service admin role enabled to publish apps for your organization.
  [Publish apps in the Microsoft Teams Tenant Apps Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams)
- As far as I know, this isn't possible yet. However when people search for your bot in the topbar, they can add the bot to a team or to their personal workspace.